# php strstr not detecting substring in a arabic string

Tags: php, arabic

Can anyone please tell me ,How to make string matching function work with Arabic keywords?
                 The Following keywords are detected as Unmatched in php. Though these are matching in normal browser searching.

```
    if (strstr('الهيئة العامة للقوى العاملة', 'قوى العامله') != false) {
       echo'in';
          } else {
          echo'out';
           }die;
```

Result comes as 'out'.

Thanks

Comment: worked fine for me, got back `in`.

Comment: Hi @Fred-ii- but i am always getting out. Can you aid me what can be possible reason?

Comment: what's the file's encoding and the server it's on? I can't replicate the error with any encodings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: maybe `stristr()` will work http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php but I can't see how that would make a difference.

Comment: Yes @Fred-ii-  stristr() isn't making any difference. :(

Comment: Thanks. @MittulAtTechnoBrave. php version may be the issue. mine is 5.4.43.

Comment: @brstdev may be .. I am not so sure ... try to put my code into your version and check whether its working or not. If not then it may be .. else lets see.

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave . can you aid me when i put the same access same values via variables , i am getting as 'out'. https://eval.in/763715

Comment: is there `setlocale` with arabic before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this .. I have **PHP Version 5.6.23**

```
<?php 
$string = 'الهيئة العامة للقوى العاملة';
$find_me = 'قوى العاملة';
if (strstr($string, $find_me) != false) {
       echo'in';
          } else {
          echo'out';
           }die;

?>
```

You can see output here https://eval.in/764085

Comment: But following doesn't work. @Mittul
It gives out when put in variable.
        <?php  $single_description_data='الهيئة العامة للقوى العاملة';
         $single_organization='القوى العاملة';
       if (strstr($single_description_data, $single_organization) != false) {
       echo'in';
          } else {
          echo'out';
           }die;

           

?>

https://eval.in/763715

Comment: @brstdev ok i have updated my answer above with variables. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

The result for the match you are doing should be `out`, so it's working just fine for you. There is no match for the search you are doing since the last letter in the word العاملة is different between the two strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-save the page in

> UTF-8 Wihtout Bom

this work for me